# Changing div background on audio play

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, playback

I'm trying to get a setup where clicking on a div plays audio (this is working), and changes the background image of another div (not working). The audio also pauses if the button is clicked again during playing, and the background image needs to keep up, as it's similar to a pause/play visual.

What've I got wrong here that it isn't working?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8/>
    <title>Janice's Button</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #button {
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-size: contain;
        }

        #clicker {
            z-index: 1000;
            position: absolute;
            left: 30%;
            top: 10%;
            width: 40%;
            border: 1px solid red;
            border-radius: 100%;
        }

        .unpressed {
            background:  url("ButtonImgUnpressed.jpg") no-repeat center top;
        }

        .pressed {
            background:  url("ButtonImgPressed.jpg") no-repeat center top;
        }


        #clicker:before{
            content: "";
            display: block;
            padding-top: 100%;  /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
        }

        .new
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="button" class="unpressed">
    </div>
    <div id="clicker" onClick="play()"></div>
    <audio id="audio" src="Rocky.mp3"></audio>
    <script>
        function play() {
            var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
            var button = document.getElementById('button')
            if (audio.paused) {
                audio.play();
                $('#button').removeClass('unpressed');
                $('#button').addClass('pressed');
            }else{
                audio.pause();
                audio.currentTime = 0
                $('#button').removeClass('pressed');
                $('#button').addClass('unpressed');
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Thank you so much! I'm sure it's a silly mistake/simple fix - I'm very new to js...

Comment: Where did you place ButtonImgPressed.jpg?

Comment: What do you mean by `the background image needs to keep up`? When the audio is paused and played again, should the image change?

Comment: I changed image & audio url and executed your code. The `changes the background image of another div (not working)` works pretty well. You may need to check the image url used for `#button`.

Comment: All images are in the same folder as the html file, hence the simple paths. @shaochuancs thanks for giving it a go, what url path change did you try?

Comment: Update: tried with web urls and still not working

`.unpressed {
background:  url("http://cdn2-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/30-impossibly-cute-puppies/impossibly-cute-puppy-8.jpg") no-repeat center top;
   }

   .pressed {
    background:  url("http://cdn3-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/30-impossibly-cute-puppies/impossibly-cute-puppy-15.jpg") no-repeat center top;
   }`

Comment: Update: Also tried using a subfolder with a path of "Images/ButtonImgPressed.jpg" but still no luck. It finds the first image every time, but won't change.

Comment: Your code works well. I created a jsfiddle, please check: https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/tw6wenga/1/

Comment: Please note both image and audio files need time to load, so after click the button for the first time, it will take some time to see the image change and hear the music.

Comment: Thanks for putting so much effort into it @shaochuancs ! I found the mistake, and it was super dumb - I hadn't imported jQuery correctly, so $ was undefined